# why state always be 0, even after using useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I expect it should be a time counter.
useCallback will refresh after the time change, so time will be 1 in the second time,
but still is 0

I tried to use useCallback but didn't work

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

import {interval} from 'rxjs'
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const inter$ = interval(1000);

function App(){
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const callback = useCallback(()=> {
      setTime(time+1);
      console.log('hella');
    }, [time])

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('hello')
    inter$.subscribe(callback)

  }, [])

  return <div>{time}</div>
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

always show 1

this is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactademo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `useEffect` the callback doesn't change since it's not a dependency. Thus, the time inside the subscription callback is always 0.

Working solution with `Rx.js`:
`setTime` call is based on prevState inside callback function.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

import { interval } from "rxjs";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";

const inter$ = interval(1000);

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
    inter$.subscribe(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1);
      console.log("hella");
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>{time}</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Another explanation would be that `time` is always 0 because in the current context of the subscription to `inter$`, the variable `time` has the value 0 and would never be updated.

Comment: @Rallen but I have used  useCallback which will update callback due to dependencies changes

Comment: whatever, maybe I just misunderstood the official document

Comment: Following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/42y0o0o06w) shows that `time` variable inside the callback still has value 0.

Answer (score 1):

change setTime(time+1); to setTime(time=>time+1);
Heres the full code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

import {interval} from 'rxjs'
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const inter$ = interval(1000);

function App(){
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const callback = useCallback(()=> {
      setTime(time=>time+1);
      console.log('hella');
    }, [time])

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('hello')
    inter$.subscribe(callback)

  }, [])

  return <div>{time}</div>
}



render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactademo-nqsmzc)

Comment: why useCallback did not update the time inside callback

Comment: Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).   it should update the time inside callback as I expect

Comment: How the dependency should change has to be written inside the 'setState'( in your case  setTIme ) method . So basically setTIme receives the time as an argument and updates increments time by 1

Comment: second argument of `useEffect` should be `[callback]` - see also [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) eslint rule